# 2 movieclips not playing simultaneously located on the same frame nested withing a movieclip as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have two movieclips on the same frame but on different layers located within the movieclip. The first movieclip plays just fine. However, the second one isn't going ahead even a single frame. The code that I have mentioned below is located withing the second movieclip containing background image. And I think this code is causing the issue because when I remove this it plays perfectly fine. The function of this code is to automatically re-size background image with the browser dimensions. The whole code just worked fine on the main timeline.However, when I shifted it inside a movieclip its causing an issue.

```
//set stage for FBF
stage.align = "TL";
stage.scaleMode = "noScale";

//define dynamic aspect ratios
var bg_mainHeight = bg_main.height / bg_main.width;
var bg_mainWidth = bg_main.width / bg_main.height;

//add event listener to the stage
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, sizeListener);

//conditional statement to account for various initial browswer sizes and proportions
function scaleProportional():void {
    if ((stage.stageHeight / stage.stageWidth) < bg_mainHeight) {
        bg_main.width = stage.stageWidth;
        bg_main.height = bg_mainHeight * bg_main.width;
    } else {
        bg_main.height = stage.stageHeight;
        bg_main.width = bg_mainWidth * bg_main.height;
    };  
}

//center bg_mainture on stage
function centerbg_main():void {
    bg_main.x = stage.stageWidth / 1000;
    bg_main.y = stage.stageHeight / 1000;
}

// make listener change bg_mainture size and center bg_mainture on browser resize
function sizeListener(e:Event):void {
    scaleProportional();
    centerbg_main();
}

//run initial locations and size
scaleProportional();
centerbg_main();
```

Comment: why this? stage.stageWidth / 1000;

Comment: It was set to stage.stageWidth / 2; initially but it was causing the bg image to not align properly. The whole code just worked fine on the main timeline.However, when I shifted it inside a movieclip its causing an issue.

Comment: You shouldn't write come inside movieclips (for maintenance purpose mainly). `bg_main` won't exist in your movieclip and may generate an error, check your output console.

Comment: bg_main is the instance name give to the background image which is located inside the second movieclip. And any errors are also not displayed.

Comment: Kodiak is correct in that adding actionscript inside movieclips isn't the best way to code, but if you prefer, try MovieClip(root).stage.stageWidth

Answer (score 0):

Yes, typically if your bg_main movieclip has it's registration point centrally this would be (assuming bg_main has been added directly to the stage):

```
function centerbg_main():void {
    bg_main.x = -stage.stageWidth / 2;
    bg_main.y = -stage.stageHeight / 2;
}
```

or if the registration point is top left it would be:

```
function centerbg_main():void {
    bg_main.x = 0;
    bg_main.y = 0;
}
```

You could also check that both movieclips have been correctly given instance names.